# Reading a file using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have a large sized file. Each line in that file maps to a database record. So I need to read that file line by line and persist each record into the database. Suppose I use multiple threads to read that file.

Is there a way in java wherein one thread can read lines from line number 1...50 and other thread reads lines from line number 51..100. In the similar way I will have multiple threads which will be reading from that single file.

Comment: If the lines all are the same length, you could seek to the required position on a different file handle owned by each thread.  But if the lines are variable lengths, you’re going to need to read each line one at a time to determine the required offset to being reading in each thread.  At that point, you’d be better off reading in one thread as fast as possible, and forwarding the data read to the other threads for processing.

Comment: Reading from multiple locations in a file simultaneously may be possible with an SSD, but with a mechanical drive, any gains you hope to achieve through threading will be lost by the time taken to keep seeking to different locations in the file.

Comment: @AJNeufeld If I want to read from multiple locations in a file, Is there any java API available for the same?

Comment: Oracle has a tutorial on [random access files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html)